# python selenium "Explicit Waits" for frame

Tags: python, selenium

In the same page same step, if use "wait" will get error message
"NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with name == rw"

if use "switch_to_frame" will success switch the frame..

why have the different?

1)

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 300)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_name('rw')))
```

2)

```
driver.switch_to_frame('rw')
```

3)

```
class cm(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://mytestweb.com"


    def testcm(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get(self.base_url)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
        self.main_wh = driver.window_handles
##        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'Frame2')))
        wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,'rw')))
##        driver.switch_to_frame('rw')
```

if i tried use 3) will get timeout message

Comment: i change my selenium lib 2.44 to 2.45 no more this issue
thx all

Answer (score 7):

Most probably the element with name *rw*, which actually takes time to load is not loaded properly before the look up happened. Basically, you are looking for same element before the expected condition to come into place. A better implementation would be the following:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 300)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,'rw')))
```

See the [doc](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: Can you please provide full stack trace?

Comment: Wow, haven't ever noticed this `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` expected condition. Learned smth new.

Comment: @alecxe I never used that either.